# Is it possible to use Amazon Cognito with LDAP?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito

Amazon Cognito supports OPENID auth and OATH. Is it possible to use LDAP instead to authenticate the user?

Answer (score 8):

You can support any authentication system with Cognito, but you will need to use a slightly different authentication flow than existing public providers. Instead of calling Cognito directly from the device you will need to construct your own backend that will handle the authentication then call Cognito to establish the trust of your identity.

Please see the following for more details:

- [Amazon Cognito : Announcing Developer Authenticated Identities](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1YVAQ4NZKBWF5/Amazon-Cognito-Announcing-Developer-Authenticated-Identities)
- [Understanding Amazon Cognito Authentication Part 2: Developer Authenticated Identities](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2FL1QAPDE0UAH/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-2-Developer-Authenticated-Ident)